# How can this code to be more shorter? in input

Tags: javascript

How can this code to be more shorter to avoid duplicating?

For example, I have  `insert1` to `insert100`

```
function insert1(){
    if($("#out_qty1").val() > 0)
       jQuery("#in_out1").val("in");
    else if($("#out_qty1").val() < 0)
       jQuery("#in_out1").val("out");
}

function insert2(){
    if($("#out_qty2").val() > 0)
       jQuery("#in_out2").val("in");
    else if($("#out_qty2").val() < 0)
       jQuery("#in_out2").val("out");
}

function insert100(){
  if($("#out_qty100").val() > 0)
      jQuery("#in_out100").val("in");
  else if($("#out_qty100").val() < 0)
     jQuery("#in_out100").val("out");
}
```

Comment: Why not passing the index/id/count, etc: `function insert(index) {.... $("#out_qty" + index);  and so on}`

Comment: Why not use a `class` name and write the function once to execute for all elements? What are you using to call the functions? OnChange? OnInput? OnClick? If you can give more information and a example of the HTML I might be able to help you with this. **Also** No need for the `else if`, you can just use `else` since the first condition will be true/false and if not then your else will execute rather than checking the only other condition is true which it must be since it can only be more that or less than 0.... unless you use `else` for equal to 0.

Comment: Here is a simple example [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/saq8nfho/)

Comment: thank you very much. i use dinamic add/delete. html: <td><input type="text" name="out_qty[]" id="out_qty"<?= ($k+1) ?>" class="css-checkbox12" value="<?=$out_qty[$k]?>" onKeyUp="total_out_qty(this); insert<?= ($k+1) ?>();" size='7' maxlength='9'>
                             
                </td>
    <td><input type=text name="in_out[]" id="in_out<?= ($k+1) ?>" class="box" placeholder="名稱" value="<?php echo $in_out[$k]; ?>" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="out_qty_date[]" id="out_qty_date<?=($k+1)?>" value="<?=$out_qty_date[$k]?>" ></td>

Comment: my script is    +'<td><input type="text" name="out_qty[]" class="css-checkbox12" id="out_qty'+(index+1)+'"   value="'+value_arr['out_qty']+'" onkeyup="total_out_qty(this); insert'+(index+1)+'();" > </td>'
   +'<td><input type="text" name="in_out[]" id="in_out'+(index+1)+'" value="'+value_arr['in_out']+'"></td>'

Comment: @plusand If you can provide a working example of what you are currently working with maybe by using [**PasteBin**](https://pastebin.com/) to supply me the example I might be able to make the required changes and place comments in the source code to explain the changes. As shown in my previous [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/saq8nfho/) it is possible to use one function and event handler to deal with all 1-100 inputs but I cannot give you that example until I see how/when/where your table/inputs are created.

Comment: @plusand If you can provide the [**PasteBin**](https://pastebin.com/) soon I will try help you but I will be going offline within the next hour so without it I cannot assist you any further. If you want you could explain the expectations & use of your table and other events. I might be able to tie them into something much more simple to work with....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use an argument for your function and pass through a number, allowing you to have one function.

```
function insert(num) {
    if($("#out_qty" + num).val() > 0)
       $("#in_out" + num).val("in");
    else if($("#out_qty" + num).val() < 0)
       $("#in_out" + num).val("out");
}
```

So now in order to use `insert1()` you can instead write `insert(1)` and so on.

You can even go past 100 (ie doing `insert(99999)`) if you wish to do so.

Comment: I think the `HTML` in the `javascript` is an attempt to format the source code into the question.

Comment: @NewToJS Ah, okay. That makes sense

Comment: I have edited the question. The Original post didn't show the `<br>` tags so whoever edited the question after didn't remove them when formatting the question. I have also attempted to make the question more clear but to give a solid answer/solution could be difficult without seeing the relevant `HTML` and knowing how those functions are called. Many different methods could be used/given without knowing how is executed or structured in the `HTML`.

Comment: @NewToJS Yeah, I agree. I've just given them this solution for now and if they reply with more information I'll modify it. Thanks :)

Comment: This is a good solution and will work providing the changes to the function call can be made. You can only work with the limited information given. I personally keep examples in the comments when the question isn't very clear or provide enough information/source code but that is a personal choice of mine. Still **+1** since you have provided a working solution.

Comment: thank you. this is my code. is not working.   +'<tr>'
   +'<td><input type="text" name="out_qty[]" class="css-checkbox12" id="out_qty'+(index+1)+'"   value="'+value_arr['out_qty']+'" onkeyup="total_out_qty(this); insert'+(index+1)+'();" size="7" maxlength="9" > </td>'
   +'<td><input type="text" name="in_out[]" id="in_out'+(index+1)+'" value="'+value_arr['in_out']+'"  size="12" maxlength="16" class="box" ></td>'
  
  +'</tr>'

Comment: @plusand can you add this to your original question and outline where this fits in with your program?

Comment: @plusand If you are having problems with adding/editing your question to format the source code feel free to use [**PasteBin**](https://pastebin.com/) and I will do my best to edit your question for you. Please only include the relevant source code since this isn't normally something I would do. It is down to the O.P to read how to submit and format a suitable question before submitting but on this occasion I am willing to take a step further to help you with your question.

Comment: @NickParsons From what **Plusand** has posted in the comments of the `HTML` I can only guess it could be dynamically created/added hence all of the concatenations being used.

Comment: @NewToJS Yeah, it seems that way.

Comment: @plusand From what I can understand of your code you would need to change how you use your insert function (see answer) and instead use this modified string:
`+'<tr>' +'<td><input type="text" name="out_qty[]" class="css-checkbox12" id="out_qty'+(index+1)+'" value="'+value_arr['out_qty']+'" onkeyup="total_out_qty(this); insert('+(index+1)+');" size="7" maxlength="9" > </td>' +'<td><input type="text" name="in_out[]" id="in_out'+(index+1)+'" value="'+value_arr['in_out']+'" size="12" maxlength="16" class="box" ></td>' +'</tr>'`

Comment: wow. thank you very much. now it is working. have a nice day. i thank you are kind person. and speciallist.

Comment: sorry i`m first here. so i checked not useful. very sorry. you`re answer is very useful for me.

Comment: @New To JS --- you`re answer is very useful for me

Comment: @plusand Here to help so to hear my input is useful to you is good :) I wish you luck with your project and always happy to help.